# Shell script simulator for windows

Tags: linux, windows, shell

Is there any simulator in witch I can write shell scripts, and run them that works on windows?  Or something like terminal simulator for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you think about cygwin? It's a port of most common GNU utils including bash for windows.

Answer (score 3):

[`Cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) would provide the functionality you require, along with a host of other Unix utilities.